# get string value from observable array in angular2 nativescript

Tags: angular, typescript, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I pushed json datas into observable array.I need to get the only the address from ShowData.That means just a string type i need to get the address value based on the position.

**ShowData.ts:**

```
 class ShowData{

  constructor(public id:number, public name:string, public address:string, public code:string) {
  }

 }
```

**ts file:**

```
  private arrList: ObservableArray<ShowData> = new ObservableArray<ShowData>();

openData(pos : number){    --->listview item position


   let getValue: any = this.arrList.get(pos);  // this is not worked


}
```

Based on the listview item position, I need to get only the arrList address.

Comment: ObservaleArray is part of NativeScripts Observables that are not compatible with RxJS's Observables and Angular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observable arrays use [`.getItem`](https://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/classes/_data_observable_array_.observablearray.html#getitem) to retrieve the item from array (not `.get`)

```
openData(pos : number){   
   let getValue: any = this.arrList.getItem(pos).address;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the address, the following will help

```
openData(pos : number){    --->listview item position
   let getValue: any = this.arrList[pos].address;
}
```

Comment: `this.arrList.getItem(pos).address` ;)

Comment: in console I'm getting cannot read propery address of undefined.   console.log("address", getValue);

Comment: are you sure the `pos` you passed into the function is valid? ie are you sure the `pos` isnt greater than the array length?

Comment: I will check and let you know.

Comment: @NicolaeSurdu your comment `this.arrList.getItem(pos).address` wroked fine.thanks for this answer. Can you post this as an answer?

Comment: @NicolaeSurdu sorry.i thought both were different user